# ArcGIS Desktop 10 - MyBase.UpdateBitmap()

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.0, vb.net

I am changing one icon on my extension toggle toolbar in runtime using:

MyBase.[UpdateBitmap](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/serveradf_net/componenthelp/index.html#/UpdateBitmap_Method/0004000004m4000000/)(New Bitmap(Me.GetType(), bitmapResourceName))

This works fine but I get a border/highlight around my image.
What can I do to prevent that?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop version 10.

Comment: what are the dimensions of your bitmap?  Also I'm not certain, but you might get a resource leak with your code ... I'd recommend instantiating all the bitmaps you need at startup and assign to member variables, instead of calling New Bitmap multiple times for the same bitmap.

Comment: Are you using a partially transparent PNG for your icon? If so, this answer might be applicable: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22037/arcobjects-setting-image-of-a-command-button-to-a-partially-transparent-bitmap