# ArcObjects: Setting image of a command button to a partially transparent bitmap

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, .net, add-in, ux

In an ArcMap 10 add-in, I am attempting to create a toggle button of sorts whose image changes based on the button's state.

[This answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/1312/753) describes how to set an add-in button's image programmatically and I am using the same technique. The problem is that this method does not appear to support full alpha channel transparency, only single-color transparency, so those fancy PNG icons they added at ArcGIS 10 don't look quite right.

The button's image is set initially by the add-in framework (using a 32-bit PNG file with alpha channel) -- the image looks as you would expect with proper partial transparency.

To create the image toggling behavior, in the button's `OnClick` method, I check the state of a boolean variable and set the button's image (using the technique in the above-mentioned answer) to one of two bitmaps stored as resources in the add-in assembly. This all works fine except that the button's image is given a gray background instead of a transparent background.

I have searched around a bit and come to the conclusion that ESRI's [`GetIPictureDispFromBitmap`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/GetIPictureDispFromBitmap_Method/00020000283w000000/) method converts from a GDI+ bitmap to a GDI bitmap and in doing so loses the alpha channel of the original bitmap.

I have found a solution to this issue and will post it as an answer shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To maintain partial alpha channel transparency, an [`IPictureDisp`](http://preview.library.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680762%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object must be created using some unmanaged code, described in [this post](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rgregg/converting-bitmaps-to-ipicturedisp) on Ryan Gregg's blog.

Copy the [C#](http://officeblogs.net/rgregg/PictureDispConverter.cs.txt) ([mirror](http://pastebin.com/g2t3RDFi)) or [VB.NET](http://officeblogs.net/rgregg/PictureDispConverter.vb.txt) ([mirror](http://pastebin.com/QXHSX5f8)) code to a new code file and add it to your project. Then, instead of the technique in the previously-mentioned answer, set [`ICommandItem.FaceID`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002300000079000000) to the return value of `PictureDispConverter.ToIPictureDisp`, passing in your original bitmap.

For example:

```cs
UID uid = new UIDClass();
uid.Value = ThisAddIn.IDs.MyButton;
ICommandItem cmdItem = ArcMap.Application.Document.CommandBars.Find(uid, true, true);
cmdItem.FaceID = PictureDispConverter.ToIPictureDisp(Resources.MyButtonEnabledState);
```

The partially-transparent areas of the original bitmap should be maintained.

Comment: In pasting this code into my project, there is no reference to the variable 'stdole'.  Do you know what this is supposed to be?

Comment: stdole.dll is a Microsoft Office Primary Interoperability Assembly (PIA): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195478%28office.11%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks!  Found it.  Didn't expect a referenced dll to be called 'stdole'.